# Error Apex:input datetime-local

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, datetime

Hi Im using this code on my page:

```
< apex:input type="datetime-local" styleClass="form-control" id="fechapesoinput" value="{!npesofechaPost}"  required="true"/>
```

The problem is that when I pick the time and I save it into a custom field Datetime, the time is one hour less than the hour I selected.

How can I change the GTM or adjust the hor properly.

At this moment im solving this ussue doing this at the back-end

```
m.Fecha__c =fechaRegistro.addHours(1);
```

but this is no solution as long as in my country we change de time every 6 months. This has to be automatic.

Comment: Depends on the timezone of the queried user and the Organization timezone.  Please mention them as well.

Comment: I checked my org profile and the timezone is well configured. ' Zona horaria predeterminada (GMT+01:00) Hora de Europa Central (Europe/Paris) '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem doing this.

```
public Double offset{get{
        TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
        //Milliseconds to Day
        return tz.getOffset(DateTime.now()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24.0);
    }} 

> <apex:outputText value="{0,date, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}"> <apex:param
> value="{!chats.CreatedDate+offset}"/></apex:outputText>
```