# Issue with apex:input datetime

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I have a page where a patient enters the appointment date for consulting, I m showing a dateTime input fields as

`<apex:input type="datetime-local" value="{!appointmentDate1}" styleClass="bRadius slds-input"/>`

But this tag is directly saving whatever the patient gives into database, Simple its saving the local time as GMT, the patient is giving time in local time zone, So now if I open the record then I see different time, Its converting the time into user's time zone.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have the reputation to comment. You may want to check here, making the offset visible to the page: [Error Apex:input datetime-local](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197965/error-apexinput-datetime-local)